# Powershell - File path, is not a recognized as the name of a cmdlet. function script file

Tags: powershell

I am getting the following error,

*Errors caught - TRAPPED: System.Management.Automation.RemoteException with message TRAPPED: The term 'D:\ServiceNow\RDC-
Dev-All\agent\scripts\PowerShell\ImMigration_script.ps1' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script fil
e, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and t
ry again.*

The issue appears to be with the invoke-command

```
Invoke-Command -Session $Session -ScriptBlock  $theCommand2
```

i have tired using -FilePath with no luck.
Also tired passing the command and param separately :

```
Invoke-Command -Session $Session -ScriptBlock  $theCommand2 -argumentlist $leName
```

I am triggering the script using:

```
D:\ServiceNow\RDC-Dev-All\agent\scripts\PowerShell\invokLyncUAdd.ps1 -param1 'CN=lync2013testuser1,CN=Users,DC=test,DC=COMPANY,DC=com' -param2 AD\sys-LyncProATSC -param3 Z0185-XAP0007-S.test.COMPANY.com
```

###############################################################################

```
param( $param1, $param2, $param3 )

$ErrorActionPreference = "Stop"

# trap {
#             write-output $("TRAPPED: " + $_.Exception.GetType().FullName);
#             write-output $("TRAPPED: " + $_.Exception.Message);
#             break
#}

$leName = $param1
$leName = ("'" + "$leName" + "'")

$thePath = 'D:\ServiceNow\RDC-Dev-All\agent\scripts\PowerShell'
$theCommand = $thePath+"\ImMigration_script.ps1 -param1 $leName"
$theCommand2 = [Scriptblock]::Create($theCommand)

# Write-Host "We use string $theCommand below"

$Account = $param2
$useP = Get-Content $thePath\'Information.txt'
$Prompt =  convertto-securestring $useP -AsPlainText -Force
$leHost = $param3
try{

$Credential = new-object -typename System.Management.Automation.PSCredential 
-argumentlist $Account, $Prompt
$Timeout = New-PSSessionOption -IdleTimeout 60000
$Session = New-PSSession -ComputerName $leHost -Credential $Credential -
Authentication Credssp -SessionOption $Timeout -ErrorAction Stop
Invoke-Command -Session $Session -ScriptBlock  $theCommand2 
}
catch
{
    $exceptType = $("TRAPPED: " + $_.Exception.GetType().FullName);
    $exceptMess = $("TRAPPED: " + $_.Exception.Message);

}
finally
{
    if($exceptType) { "Errors caught - $exceptType with message $exceptMess " }    }
```

Any help would be great, Thanks

Comment: Are you expecting the file to exist on the local or remote computer?

Comment: @gms0ulman hi, i have both file on my local server, and i believe the idea is to run the $command2 on the remote machine

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The session is being executed on the remote computer, and I believe that's where PowerShell will expect the file to exist.

I would approach it by attempting to load the local script as a scriptblock so that it is in memory:

```
$thePath     = 'D:\ServiceNow\RDC-Dev-All\agent\scripts\PowerShell'
$theCommand  = $thePath+"\ImMigration_script.ps1"
$theCommand2 = [Scriptblock]::Create(Get-Content $theCommand)
```

Then, from your question:

```
Invoke-Command -Session $Session -ScriptBlock  $theCommand2 -argumentlist $leName
```

Please let me know if this works.

Answer (score 0):

If the file is in local, then

```
powershell.exe -noexit -file 'D:\ServiceNow\RDC-Dev-All\agent\scripts\PowerShell\invokLyncUAdd.ps1' -param1 'CN=lync2013testuser1,CN=Users,DC=test,DC=COMPANY,DC=com' -param2 'AD\sys-LyncProATSC' -param3 'Z0185-XAP0007-S.test.COMPANY.com'
```

If It is in the remote system, then make sure you are mentioning the remote path properly in the invoke-command.